# Update statement with multiple tables and Order By and LIMIT in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

When I try to run an update statement with multiple tables and Order By and LIMIT in mySql like below,

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Percent` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_products`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE
tbl_product_rate t1,
  ( SELECT tbl_products.id, (rate * number) AS prt
    FROM tbl_products left join tbl_products_rate on tbl_products.id = tbl_products_rate.id GROUP BY id
  ) t2
SET
  t1.option = t2.prt
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.id ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 1;
END
```

I have an error like below,

```
[Last executed query: EXECUTE mdb2_statement_mysql_142db9909b0277f32407f2a5d4da240eabf37dd822 USING @0]
[Native code: 1221]
[Native message: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY]
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix the above update statement so that order by and limit can be used for update statement
with multiple tables?

p.s. If I run the update statement without ORDER BY and LIMIT it would update all the rows that exist in the table without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql manual on update statement says:

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables. However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT with a multiple-table UPDATE.

This means that you need to convert your multi table update statement into single table ones to be able to perform the operation.

From the query it seems to me that you want a single value (`rate * number`) from the `tbl_products` table.

The selection criteria is unclear to me, since you are ordering on the field you use for joining, meaning the field will have exactly the same value for all records and you do not use any aggregate function with your group by. This means your subquery is against the sql standards and only run in mysql because you do not have the only full group by sql mode set. You also do not refer to the record being updated, so no idea how this query relates to the current record.

Because of this I cannot suggest how to rewrite the join into a subquery. But that's what you need to do: rewrite your join as a subquery.

Comment: Thanks, Shadow, I simplified the part,(rate * number) for posting purpose, since the calculation was so long and confusing. I'm still confused how and where I should use subquery on my code and I'd appreciate if you could show me an example which doesn't have to be accurate at all. Just an idea of it in "my case" so that I'll make it work based upon "my situation".

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I cannot suggest a solution because I do not understand what you want to achieve.